# JavaScript won't change iframe src correctly

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I started taking an interest in JS recently and have been fooling about. I have wriiten some embedded JS in my HTML code and was wondering why it wasn't working properly. The code seems to always change the `src` to `http://www.learn ... fillitin_mult_twelve.xml` no matter which box is selected. Test this [here](http://swaba.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/games/multiplication.html).

```
        <iframe height="400" width="600" id="multGame" src="http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_six.xml"></iframe>


        <select id="timestableSlt" onchange="changeGame()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
        </select> 
        <script>
        function changeGame() {
            var e = document.getElementById("timestableSlt");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;


            if (strUser = "1") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_one.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "2") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_two.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "3") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_three.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "4") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_four.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "5") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_five.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "7") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_seven.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "8") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_eight.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "9") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_nine.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "10") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_ten.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "11") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_eleven.xml";
            } else if (strUser = "12") {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_twelve.xml";
            } else {
            document.getElementById('multGame').src = "http://www.learninggamesforkids.com/_games/Main.swf?xml=assets/fill_in_blanks/fillitin_mult_six.xml";
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: the problem is your comparation '=' .... use 'strUser === "5"'

Comment: @CMedina I'll try that!

Comment: @CMedina That worked. Thanks! I'll accept that as an answer if you post it ;-)

Comment: Also you should change `selected="selected"` to just `selected`.

Comment: @TheMintyMate Alright, I just followed what w3schools said. I'll change that...

Comment: That is fair enough :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your comparation `=`. Instead, use `strUser === "5"`

Answer (score 0):

```
strUser = "1"
```

is setting the value of strUser to "1" and it repeats the process, setting it n+1 until it gets to the last else if statement, which is why strUser always ends up being equal to 12.

You need to use two equal signs if you want to compare the values (instead of set a value).

```
strUser == "1"
```